# C++ Uniform initialization doesn't work with "expected ';' at end of declaration"

Tags: c++, variables

I'm the beginner of C++. I set development environment in vscode in Mac.
But I trapped in variable initialization.
Copy initialization and direct initialization are ok, but uniform initialization doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a(0);

    int b = 0;

    int c{0};
    
    int d = {0};

    int e;

    std::cout << "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, `int c{0};` doesn't work. It failed to build.
It printed `error: expected ';' at end of declaration`

[image]

What can I try to solve this problem??

I don't know if it helps, but I'll upload ".vscode".

```
// c_cpp_properties.json
{

    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [
          "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }
```

```
// launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
// tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "&&",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ 활성 파일 빌드",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "디버거에서 생성된 작업입니다."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: does the program actually fail to compile?  intellisense, the red squiggle can sometimes be wrong.

Comment: Please don’t post pictures

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @NathanOliver it actually fail to compile

Comment: I put "-std=c++17" in arg part in task.json, and the code worked!!

Comment: It's because by default, clang++ uses the C++98 standard on the mac which doesn't support uniform initialization which wasn't added until C++11.  More info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).